# tar complains "No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, bash, tar

I'm using bash on Windows (distributed along with msysgit) to zip log files - one archive per date. Problem is, following script does not work and I have no idea why. 
Cut is here to get part of the filename that corresponds to a date the log was written.

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' | cut -c3-12 | head -n 5 | xargs -I common printf "%s%s\n" common "*.log" | xargs -I fg tar cvzf hello.tgz fg
```

Before last step, each line looks like this - 2014-07-04*.log
At the last step it gives me output like this:

```
tar: 2014-07-01*.log: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

I suspect it's because of a newline at the end, because when I call tar command by hand it works fine. Any ideas what I missed? I read some of the similar answers, but they don't seem to apply in my case. Archive name is for example, later I'd make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
xargs -I common printf "%s%s\n" common "*.log"
```

The `*.log` is inserted in the template *as is*. I don't understand why you put the "*" there at all. This would fix that:

```
xargs -I common printf "%s%s\n" common .log
```

However, the last `tar` command won't actually work,
because the `tar cvzf hello.tgz fg` command will be executed for each file,
and therefore you'll end up with a tar with a single file in it (the last one).

I believe this should be closer to what you want:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' | cut -c3-12 | uniq | xargs -I{} sh -c 'tar zcvf {}.tgz {}*.log'
```

If you have files like:

```
2014-07-01.1.log
2014-07-01.2.log
2014-07-02.1.log
2014-07-02.5.log
2014-07-02.6.log
```

Then the command will put the first 2 into `2014-07-01.tgz` and the last 3 into `2014-07-02.tgz`.

Comment: no, I intentionally put * there. I want all files according to this pattern to be in one .tgz archive - because there are files like 2014-07-01.0.log, 2014-07-01.1.log and so on

Comment: I would not recommend parsing ls output that way. It will break when files have whitespace in their name, and various other problems might occur. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @slhck I'm aware of that, but I don't have that many files, and I'm sure there are no spaces in filenames

Comment: I'm aware of a problem with archive name. But if I get rid of the star, tar won't group several files of the same date, will it?